# Limiting Projects based on selector

Tags: acumatica

I would like to filter the records shown on the Projects screen.  I've been given the directive to see if limiting the Selector for projects (re-writing the PXSelector for the ProjectID?) would also limit the records that show up on the screen, i.e., a user would not be able to navigate to records that aren't displayed by the Selector.  I don't think that's the case, as the screen's view is not limited by what is chosen by the Selector - but I wanted to verify this.

Also - as far as limiting the records that show up in the Selector (possibly re-writing the Selector/BQL using a where clause?) - I looked at the source DAC, and for the life of me I can't figure it out.  There is a PXSelector on the ContractID, which doesn't use the SubstituteKey that I'm familiar with, and the ContractCD also has several attributes with which I'm unfamiliar - namely the PXRestrictor AND the PXDimensionSelector.

Bottom line:

1.) What's the best way to limit the records for Project shown in the screen's Selector?  Can I just add to the PXRestrictor attribute?

2.) Would limiting the Selector's results also limit what the user can navigate to on the screen using the navigation buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you need to restrict access to primary records on a data entry screen, it's always required to customize both the lookup DAC key field and the primary data view. By design, in Acumatica key fields in DAC and the primary data view are completely independent, that is why it's required to modify both pieces to achieve the desired result.

For example, to deny access to canceled projects on the Projects screen, you should add PXRestrictorAttribute to PMProject's ContractCD field and also re-declare Project primary data view:

```
public class ProjectEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<ProjectEntry>
{
    public class cancelled : Constant<string>
    {
        public cancelled() : base(ProjectStatus.Cancelled) {; }
    }

    [PXViewName(Messages.Project)]
    public PXSelect<PMProject, Where<PMProject.baseType, Equal<PMProject.ProjectBaseType>,
        And<PMProject.nonProject, Equal<False>, And<PMProject.isTemplate, Equal<False>,
        And<PMProject.status, NotEqual<cancelled>,
        And<Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>>>>> Project;

    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<PMProject.status, NotEqual<cancelled>>),
        "Given Project/Contract '{0}' is cancelled", typeof(PMProject.contractCD))]
    public void PMProject_ContractCD_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ruslan - Just an FYI, Instead of modifying the PXRestrictor (which doesn't seem to provide a way to join tables), I actually added my joined tables to the [PXDimensionSelector] for the ContractCD field using the Cache_Attached event.